# Android app apk with debug mode has the background voice but in release mode does not have background voice?

Tags: android, release

My APP use webView to launch the H5 game,i use the USE to debug can listen the game background voice ,but after I build the Generate Signed APK and installed can not listen the game background music.

Comment: Do you try to create release without obfuscation? Change in gradle 
minifyEnabled true -> minifyEnabled false

Comment: @AlexeySokolov but if i set minifyEnable false,I can not Generate Signed APK again.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood you. But minifyEnabled just on/off obfuscation => usually debug apk work without obfuscation, as a result i thought that maybe problem with obfuscation

Comment: @AlexeySokolov can u help to check the project? If you no time.no matter thx

Comment: @AlexeySokolov i already set true in minifyEnable

Comment: Did you try to check logs? Maybe some warning, exception or anything else in it